# Convergence of a recursevely defined sequence $x_0=0 $, $x_{n+1} = 1 - (1/2) x_n ^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations

I am having trouble with an exercise where it's asked to prove the rate of convergence of a particular sequrence defined by recurrence. The sequence is:

$$\begin{cases}
x_0 =0\\
x_{n+1} = 1 - \frac{1}{2} x_n ^2
\end{cases}$$

Now I proved that it converges to $l= \sqrt{3} -1$, but I can't prove or disprove that $|x_n - l| \approx l^n$, where with $\approx$ I mean that $\exists c, C >0$ such that

$$ c l^n \leq |x_n - l| \leq C l^n . $$

Even some suggestions are welcome, it's been years since I last did this kind of exercises and maybe there are some tricks I don't remember or I didn't even know.

EDIT: It can be helpful to notice that the sequences of even and odd terms are monotonically increasing and decreasing, respectively.

EDIT 2: I tried using the sequence $y_n = x_n - l$ but the bounds don't really work out. I can bound from above by something like $(1+ \epsilon)l(x_n -l)$ and from below with $(1-\epsilon) l (x_n -l)$. Of course this $\epsilon$ depends on $n$, if it was like $\epsilon \approx 1/n$ I would have finished, but it doesn't seem to work. I may have committed some mistakes on the induction step though.

Comment: You can do this by doing induction. Consider substituing $y_n=x_n-\sqrt 3+1$, subtracting $\sqrt 3-1$ on both side and factorize. Then using strong induction to give a bound. But first, I think you should obtain a loose bound then using that to get a strong bound.

Comment: Yeah I tried it, but it doesn't seem to work. What do you mean by "loose bound"?

Comment: For example, you could first try $|x_n-\sqrt 3+1|\le C\cdot 0.99^n$. Then after that you could use this loose bound to proof the upper bound.

Comment: I have written an answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we try a loose bound. Notice that $x_0=0,x_1=1$ and $x_n\in[0,1]$. Also we can say that $x_n=1-1/2x_n^2\Rightarrow (x_n-(\sqrt{3}-1))=-(x_{n-1}-(\sqrt{3}-1))\frac{\sqrt{3}-1+x_{n-1}}{2}$. Therefore we have
$$|x_n-(\sqrt{3}-1)|=|x_{n-1}-(\sqrt{3}-1)||\frac{\sqrt{3}-1+x_{n-1}}{2}|\le|x_{n-1}-(\sqrt{3}-1)|\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

So we can know that $|x_n-\sqrt 3+1|\le (\sqrt 3-1)(\frac{\sqrt 3}{2})^n$

Now we refine our estimation: we know that

$$\begin{align}
&|x_n-(\sqrt{3}-1)|=|x_{n-1}-(\sqrt{3}-1)||\frac{\sqrt{3}-1+x_{n-1}}{2}|\\
= & |x_0-(\sqrt{3}-1)|\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}|\frac{\sqrt{3}-1+x_i}{2}|\\
= & (\sqrt{3}-1)\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}|\sqrt{3}-1+\frac{x_i-(\sqrt{3}-1)}{2}|\\
= & (\sqrt{3}-1)\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(\sqrt{3}-1)|1+\frac{x_i-(\sqrt{3}-1)}{2(\sqrt{3}-1)}|\\
\le & (\sqrt{3}-1)^{n+1}\exp(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}|\frac{x_i-(\sqrt{3}-1)}{2(\sqrt{3}-1)}|) &\text{by }1+x\le e^x\\
\le & (\sqrt{3}-1)^{n+1}\exp(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{(\sqrt 3-1)(\frac{\sqrt 3}{2})^{i}}{2(\sqrt{3}-1)})\\
\le &(\sqrt{3}-1)^{n+1}\exp(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\sqrt 3-1)(\frac{\sqrt 3}{2})^{i}}{2(\sqrt{3}-1)})=(\sqrt{3}-1)^{n+1}\exp({2+\sqrt{3}})
\end{align}$$

Take $C={\exp({2+\sqrt{3}})}(\sqrt{3}-1)$ suffice.

Similarly, we have (notice that $x_n>0$ so $\frac{x_{n}-(\sqrt{3}-1)}{2(\sqrt{3}-1)}>-\frac{1}{2}$. For $x>-1/2$ we know that $1+x\ge e^{-2|x|}$)

$$\begin{align}
&|x_n-(\sqrt{3}-1)|=|x_{n-1}-(\sqrt{3}-1)||\frac{\sqrt{3}-1+x_{n-1}}{2}|\\
= & (\sqrt{3}-1)\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(\sqrt{3}-1)|1+\frac{x_{n-1}-(\sqrt{3}-1)}{2(\sqrt{3}-1)}|\\
\ge & (\sqrt{3}-1)^{n+1}\exp(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}-2|\frac{x_{n-1}-(\sqrt{3}-1)}{2(\sqrt{3}-1)}|)\\
\ge & (\sqrt{3}-1)^{n+1}\exp(-2\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{(\sqrt 3-1)(\frac{\sqrt 3}{2})^{i}}{2(\sqrt{3}-1)})\\
\ge &(\sqrt{3}-1)^{n+1}\exp(-2\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\sqrt 3-1)(\frac{\sqrt 3}{2})^{i}}{2(\sqrt{3}-1)})=(\sqrt{3}-1)^{n+1}\exp(-{4-2\sqrt{3}})
\end{align}$$

Take $c=(\sqrt{3}-1)\exp(-{4-2\sqrt{3}})$ suffice.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

If $\ \alpha=\sqrt{3}-1\ $ then $\ \ \alpha=1-\frac{\alpha^2}{2}\ $, and
\begin{align}
x_{n+1}-\alpha&=1-\frac{x_n^2}{2}-1+\frac{\alpha^2}{2}\\
&=\frac{(x_n+\alpha)}{2}(\alpha-x_n)\ .
\end{align}
Therefore, if $\ |x_n-\alpha|<\epsilon\ $ for all $\ n>N\ $, then, for all such $\ n\ $,
\begin{align}
|x_{n+1}-\alpha|&<\left(\alpha+\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right)|x_n-\alpha|\\
&<\left(\alpha+\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right)^{n-N}|x_N-\alpha|\ .
\end{align}

Comment: Yeah but that $\epsilon$ is a bit tricky, that depdns on $N$ and trying to pass to the limit doesn't seem that obvious. Because if you want to decrease $\epsilon$ you have to increase $N$, so it gets complicated